# What happened to Mountain View Analytics?

Tags: portfolio, portfolio-optimization

I stumbled over Thomas Cover's work on algorithmic portfolio selection; apparently, an outfit called "Mountain View Analytics" attempted to implement the suggestions from Cover's research.

Unfortunately, I can't find a trace of information about whether this worked and what happened to them - does anyone have a recommendation?

Cheers,
Rotaist

Update: It seems Thomas Cover [died in 2012](http://bulletin.imstat.org/2012/05/obituary-thomas-cover-1938%E2%80%932012/), but I haven't found any more information about the fund.